# Time order problem of control variables in IV regression

Tags: regression, instrumental-variables

Y is the dependent variable, X is the independent variable, and C is a control variable. However, since X is endogenous, I plan to use an instrumental variable Z for X. From what I understand, if I conduct a two-stage analysis, in the first stage I predict X using C and Z to obtain an estimated value of X, and in the second stage, I use the estimated value of X along with C to calculate Y.

My question is about the timing of variable C. If the order of C is after X but before Y, there would be no issue with the causal order in the second stage. However, in the first stage, if I predict X using Z and C, it means I am predicting X using a future occurrence of C.

So, when doing IV Regression, should I only use control variables that occur before X in time?

Comment: What do you mean by "timing of variable C"? The phrase "the order of C is after X but before Y" makes no sense without additional information about the structure of your data. Is your data a time series? A panel? Please specify these in the question. It's best to be precise about the specification you are trying estimate; ideally you should write down the exact regression equation you have in mind.